# Как работает атака 51% для Proof of Work Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

Разбираюсь в устройстве Биткоина и застрял на моменте атаки 51%. Я понимаю, что цепочка должна быть длиннее, тогда блокчейн примет её, но хотелось бы конкретики, каким образом 51% майнеров отправляет узлам более длинную цепочку? Первое: Разве узлы могут принимать более одного блока? Спасибо!

Comment: Почему вы меня заминусовали, что я такого спросил? Нормальный вопрос человека, который хочет разобраться в устройстве блокчейна с технической точки зрения! Если сами не знаете как устроено, не надо меня минусовать! Я уверен мало кто может конкретно ответить что и как происходит. Техничнски API Биткоина вряд ли может принимать больше одного блока, отсюда и возникает логичный вопрос, а что такое более длинная цепочка, если все равно майнеры отправляют узлам по одному блоку, тогда каким нафик образом происходит эта дурацкая атака. ChatGPT, Bard, гуглопоиск и чаты в телеграм не дали мне ответа!

Answer (score 2):

1. Узлы могут принимать неограниченное число блоков. В сетях с небольшим числом узлов при нарушении взаимодействия узлов, например, из-за фрагментации сети могут возникнуть форки в тысячи блоков.
2. Поведение любого узла строится следующим образом - из всех полученных цепочек дерева он выбирает наидлиннейшую и майнит следующих блок-кандидат к ее последнему блоку. Таким образом обеспечивается наибольшая вероятность попадание блока в основную цепочку и, следовательно, получение награды за блок. По мере получения новых блоков дерево цепочек непрерывно перестраивается и появляется новый кандидат на "длиннейшую" цепочку. В принципе, при желании узел может строить цепочку вообще откуда хочет (что и делает атакующий), но тогда его блоки будут просто проигнорированы и он не получит вознаграждения.
3. Каждый узел сам определяет "свою" длиннейшую цепочку исходя из полученных им блоков и на конкретный момент времени цепочки на разных узлах могу различаться в пределах некоторго статистического хвоста: для Bitcoin это до 6 блоков, для Ethereum-1 - 3-4 блока.
4. Сложность задачи расчета "счастливого" хеша автоматически подбирается таким образом, чтобы выдержать некоторое среднее время цикла генерации блоков. Поэтому чтобы построить и внедрить свою цепочку как основную, атакующий должен иметь возможность рассчитывать "счастливый" хэш быстрее, чем все остальные узлы в сумме, иначе его цепочка всегда будет перебиваться цепочками других узлов. А для этого у атакующего должны быть вычислительные мощности более 50% от хэшрейта всей сети. По простому говорят "51%".

Где-то так.